# How to write query using jpa template

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, mongodb-query

I have used mongo repository and mongo template here to write mongodb query.

```
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String> {}

private final MongoTemplate template;
public Scheduling(MongoTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}
Query query = new Query();       
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is("READY")).with(Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("timestamp")));
List<Entity> entityList = template.find(query, Entity.class);
```

How can I use jpa template instead of mongo template to query mongodb? I need to write same query as above but using jpa template
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the `@Query` annotation and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` interface will help something like `@Query("{ 'name' : ?0 }") List<User> findUsersByName(String name);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of JPA query and refer mentioned link :

```
List<ExecutorEntity> findExecutorEntityByStatusAndSort(String status, Sort sort);
```

https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-data-mongodb-queries